# Проблемма со spinner.setSelection()

Tags: android, android-spinner

Делаю 7 спиннеров в каждом из которых 3 item-a, по нажатию на один из item-ов перехожу на новую активность, когда нажимаю на кнопочку назад, возвращаюсь к активити со своими спиннерами, хочу чтобы при возврате, в спиннере выставлялся первый item который и стоял, пробовал через setSelection(0) при запуске он меняет, но при переходе на активность со спиннерами после перехода не меняет. хотя ошибок ни каких нету.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вызывать **setSelection(0)** в **onResume()**.

Comment: Я совсем зелёный так что можете объяснить что такое onResume() и где его вписать, и как в этот самый onResume() вписать setSelection(0)

Comment: @ЯрославХлебородов переопределите в активити метод `onResume()` а уже в нем назначьте для спиннера `setSelection(n)`, где `n`- выбранная ранее позиция